# Load more files in a Gatling feeder

Tags: scala, gatling

I have several csv files in the resources folder. They have the same content, but all of them are quite big (~14gb). I would like to avoid merging them into one huge file.

Is there a way to provide multiple files (or a path to a folder) to Gatling Feeder?

Comment: Did you resolve in any way?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin yes, instead of using a feeder, I got my files into a single iterator.

Answer (score 2):

That's too user specific so that's something you'll have to implement yourself.
A feeder is just an `Iterator[Map[String, Any]]`.